# Are leaflet polylines capable to look like spheric projection?

Tags: leaflet, polyline

I want to swap from commercial googlemaps to openstreetmap and cannot find an answer to the following question:

"Old" googlemaps project show paths as "speric projections" - look here:
http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/map

I have created a map using openstreetmap and leaflet and can draw the paths using polyline. It works - but they are always "straight lines" and do not look as at googlemaps (see link above). Is there any possibility to get a path like in ge?

Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is show geodetic lines along great circles. There's a Leaflet plugin for this, at https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic .

Comment: 100% right! The miracle word what was missing during search was "geodetic" :) Many thanks - closed.